# PostgreSQL: Refer to specific nth column of WITH created temponary table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Supposing I have a temporary table created using `WITH` clause as follows:

```sql
WITH temporary_table AS (
    VALUES ('First', 1),
           ('Second', 2),
           ('Third', 3))
```

Is it possible to refer to the nth column in the `SELECT` clause? Something like:

```sql
WITH temporary_table AS (
    VALUES ('First', 1),
           ('Second', 2),
           ('Third', 3)
)
SELECT second_column
FROM temporary_table;
```

If not - is there any other way to make up some temporary table only for query purposes when having read only privileges?

I haven't found anything helpful on [WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-with.html) or [SELECT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-select.html) PostgreSQL docs.

Comment: As a side note: a common table expression (CTE, "with clause") is not a "temporary table".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give them a name, e.g as part of the WITH clause:

```
WITH temporary_table (c1, c2) AS (
    VALUES ('First', 1),
           ('Second', 2),
           ('Third', 3)
)
SELECT c2
FROM temporary_table;
```

A slightly more complicated way is to name the columns of the VALUES clause:

```
WITH temporary_table AS (
  select *
  from (
    VALUES ('First', 1),
           ('Second', 2),
           ('Third', 3)  
  ) as t(c1, c2)
)
SELECT c2
FROM temporary_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Name the columns.

For example:

```
WITH temporary_table (a, b) AS (
    VALUES ('First', 1),
           ('Second', 2),
           ('Third', 3)
)
SELECT b
FROM temporary_table;
```